# Force java to accept self signed certificates

Tags: java, certificate

OK, I know about the excepction list, but adding individual URLs to the exception filter is not the way I want to proceed. I already have click-to-run enabled, therefore if I want to run a java application I'm pretty sure I don't want java to get in the way of that.

Now, there has to be a method for disabling this annoying feature. I'm even willing to delve into the depths of java's codebase to do so.

Comment: How do expect to change java if it's not open source?

Comment: @Ramhound I was more thinking of config flags, userdata settings... perhaps if anyone had discovered anything.